# Python Dictionary from pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

How come this method results in an embedded dictionary which then I can not use to rename columns.

```
# Rename columns
cen_columns = cen_columns[['VARIABLE','LABEL_CLEAN']].set_index("VARIABLE").to_dict()
census_age.columns = census_age.columns.to_series().map(cen_columns['LABEL_CLEAN'])
```

Resulting in:

```
{'LABEL_CLEAN': {'B01001_001E': 'Total',
  'B01001_002E': 'Male',
  'B01001_003E': 'Male_Under_5',
```

where as this method is a single level dictionary that I then can use to rename columns:

```
#Rename Columns 
cen_columns = dict(zip(cen_columns['VARIABLE'], cen_columns['LABEL_CLEAN']))
census_age.rename(columns=cen_columns,inplace=True)
census_age.head(2)
```

Resulting in a straightforward dict

```
{'B01001_001E': 'Total',
  'B01001_002E': 'Male',
  'B01001_003E': 'Male_Under_5'....}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using [`pd.DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) and not [`pd.Series.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) and the former gives you a nested dict in the format `{column -> {index -> value}}` :

```
>>> cen_columns[["VARIABLE", "LABEL_CLEAN"]].set_index("VARIABLE")

# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
# `.to_dict` gives {'LABEL_CLEAN': {'B01001_001E': 'Total', ...

>>> cen_columns.set_index("VARIABLE")["LABEL_CLEAN"]

# <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
# `.to_dict` gives {'B01001_001E': 'Total', 'B01001_002E': 'Male', ...
```

To get a flattened mapper, you can fix/simplify your code this way :

```
mapper = cen_columns.set_index("VARIABLE")["LABEL_CLEAN"].to_dict()

census_age.rename(columns=mapper, inplace=True)
```